# "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar": pypyodbc + SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pypyodbc

```
|id    | language 

|123456| GE
```

I can't update data in SQL Server.

I'm beginner.I am writing telegram bot, and i want add new languages.Therefore, I use the database. 
I have a table with 2 columns, one declared as nvarchar(id), and the other as nchar(language) and i'm trying change language.

```
import pypyodbc

...
#for example
id = 123456
lang = 'EN'
#
data = ("""
           UPDATE bottest
           SET language = ?
           WHERE id = ?;
           """)
k = (id, lang)
cursor.execute(data, k).rowcount
cursor.commit()
```

Getting this error:

```
 File "C:\Users\MyPC\PycharmProjects\bottest_flask_i\venv\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1007, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
  File "C:\Users\MyPC\PycharmProjects\bottest_flask_i\venv\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 977, in ctrl_err
    raise DataError(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.DataError: ('22003', '[22003] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar.')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter values are specified in the wrong order. The parameter for `language` (in the SET clause) appears before the parameter for `id` (in the WHERE clause) so you need to specify the `language` parameter value first. That is, instead of

```python
k = (id, lang)
```

you need to use

```python
k = (lang, id)  # same order as the parameter placeholders appear in the command text
```